# what is implied by using the -L in gcc flag in gcc post-ceded by a dot

Tags: gcc

```
psp-gcc -I. -IC:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include -O2 -G0 -Wall -D_PSP_FW_VERSION=150  -L. -LC:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/lib   main.o  -lpspdebug -lpspdisplay -lpspge -lpspctrl -lpspsdk -lc -lpspnet -lpspnet_inet -lpspnet_apctl -lpspnet_resolver -lpsputility -lpspuser -lpspkernel -o controller_basic.elf
```

it uses -I.

and it also uses -L.

note the dot after each of them, that is not a grammar dot, but a dot within the command itself, that i have no idea what it does, and i doubt i will find anything on the official docs without spending days reading through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` (dot) refers to the current directory. Therefore these options are specifying that the current directory should be searched for any required header files (`-I.`) and any required libraries (`-L.`).

From the GCC manual:

```
-Idir
    Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files.

-Ldir
    Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.

-l library
    Search the library named library when linking.
```

From the POSIX specification:

```
The special filename dot shall refer to the directory specified by its predecessor.
```